# Array of Arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Objective: Given an array of strings, output an array whose each element is an array containing the original element and its index.

For Example:
input = ['red', 'violet', 'blue']

```
Use the input array to construct the following array:

[['red', 0], ['violet', 1], ['blue', 2]]
```

The Signature method_name is as given:
make_array(input_array)

The method should return nil in the following scenarios:

1. if input_array is Hash/string/Fixnum [i.e anything that is not an array]
2. if input_array is nil/empty
3. if any element of input_array is not a string [i.e input_array has to be an array of strings]

For case 1,2 and 3, try to use exception handling where in the rescue block you should return nil.

note:: The return value must be an Array of Arrays or nil

In this, how to convert array to array of arrays and how to raise these exceptions?
Since I am new to Ruby ,I find it difficult to solve.Please help me out with this.
Thanks!

Comment: _"how to raise these exceptions"_ – it's unclear where you got stuck. Do you know how to raise an exception? Do you know how to check whether an object is an array or not? Do you know how to check an array's elements?

Comment: Please don't ask two things in a a single question. Post two different questions instead. As for generating your array, look up `Array#map`. As for raising an exception, use either the `raise` keyword or the `Kernel#fail`.

Comment: here after I will have a check on it  user1934428.Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
def make_array(array)
  return unless array.is_a?(Array)
  return unless array.all?(String)
  return if array.empty?

  array.map.with_index { |element, index| [element, index ] }
end

make_array('string')
#=> nil
make_array([])
#=> nil
make_array(['string', 1234])
#=> nil
make_array(['red', 'violet', 'blue'])
#=> [["red", 0], ["violet", 1], ["blue", 2]]
```

Using an exception seems non-sense to me because it makes the code harder to understand and handling exceptions is an expensive operation. I prefer doing proper checks upfront.

Comment: `array.map.with_index { |element, index| [element, index ] }` == `array.each_with_index.to_a` ?

Comment: And yes, yes, exceptions do not make sense here.